# How to add a border to UniformGrid cells

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to add a border around elements in my WPF UniformGrid. What I've tried:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GridCell">
        <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="5"></Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

...and...

```
<UniformGrid Name="grid">
    <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridCell}"></ItemsControl>
</UniformGrid>
```

It doesn't work (no border appears). I'd like to have each child of the UniformGrid (buttons which are created programmatically, so they don't appear here) to have a border. It needs to look like, well, a grid... with horizontal and vertical gridlines delineating rows and columns.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541607/assigning-border-to-every-grid-row) question, @Carlo answer about `BorderGrid`. `DataTemplate` suggests that its content known beforehand, I think in this case it does not work.

Comment: i would look into ItemsContainerStyle

Answer (score 3):

```
<Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NumericalPatches}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="7" Columns="7"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness="3">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Text="{Binding StringFormat=F4,Path=Red}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Red"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding StringFormat=F4,Path=Green}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Green"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Text="{Binding StringFormat=F4,Path=Blue}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Blue"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding StringFormat=F4,Path=Chroma}" FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```